# How to disable image button onlclick in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I have a GridView in this GridView there is a column which I use to select date with the use of asp:CalendarExtender. I have multiple rows in GridView which are dynamically generated.
When I click the image button calender pops up and I choose my date.

In some rows I want the User to select date when he clicks image button of that row. sometime I don't want to allow him to select date. 
When he tries to change the date or click on the image button, he should get alert message saying that you are not allowed to change the date. 
I want to handle it from client side. So please suggest me how to do this. 
this is the aspx code.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="StartDateTime"  CssClass="search_area_text_vm_small" onclick = "javascript:DateClick(this.id);"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/image3.jpg" />
          <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="StartDateTime"  PopupButtonID="Image1" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" ></asp:CalendarExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="StartDateTime"
                            ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the OnClientDateSelectionChanged event of the CalendarExtender.

Use below code:

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="StartDateTime"  PopupButtonID="Image1" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkIfDateSelected()" >
</asp:CalendarExtender>

<javascript>
function checkIfDateSelected(){
var dateTextBox=document.getElementByid('StartDateTime');
if(dateTextBox!='')
{
alert ('Date once selected cannot be changed');
return false;
}
</javascript>
```

This will show the info pop up and prevent the form submission if the date has been selected already.

Comment: Why ImageButton if he needs to handle client side script?

Comment: It could be a asp button or ImageButton as they come with OnClientClick property to specify additional client-side script that executes when an Button control's Click event is raised, whereas asp Image does not. (i'm sorry i did not notice CalendarExtender, so i've edited my answer)